# How to implement Idle time backup feature in android

Tags: android

I am supposed to implement idle time backup feature in an application. Can any one help me with any example code or references.

A used case for the above feature would be back up contacts,calender. Primarily I need to implement idle time back up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean when your app is idle and not when the phone is idle:

Use an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) when your app goes idle to start a backup after a specific delay.

Cancel the alarm if your app restarts before the alarm fires.

`OnPause` and `onResume` methods of the Activity can be used to determine when the app is idle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i shall try it as mentioned above.